# Custom 404 page redirect not working in IIS7.5 when missing URL is in a sub-folder

Tags: asp.net, redirect, iis-7, web-config, http-status-code-404

I have a site with a mixture of .html and .aspx pages running on a W2K8 R2 server with IIS 7.5.  The site is a redevelopment of an older site and all of the URLs and most of the content has changed from the old site to the new site.  I expect to get a number of 404s as people use old links.

I want to redirect 404 errors to a custom page (/404.aspx).  This is (part) of my web.config:

```
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite"> 
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="/404.aspx" />
    </customErrors>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
      <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/404.aspx"  
             responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    </httpErrors>
  </system.webServer>
```

The managed pipeline mode for the App Pool for this site is `Integrated`.

This redirection to my custom 404.aspx page is working well some of the time, and other times it is only kind of working.   These kind of URLs redirect just fine:

- http://www.example.com/no-such-page.aspx
- http://www.example.com/no-such-page.html

However, these kind of URLs (where the missing page is in a sub-folder) get a strange result:

- http://www.example.com/folder/not-a-real-page.aspx
- http://www.example.com/folder/not-a-real-page.aspx

What happens with the sub-folder URLs is I get the HTML markup from the 404.aspx page, but the page doesn't render properly because all of the CSS and script references in the page are missing, near as I can tell from sniffing network traffic, because **somehow IIS is trying to insert the `/folder/` into the URL** for resources with relative paths in my 404.aspx page.  For example, my 404.aspx page, which is in my site's root folder has a reference to `css/style.css` but for a 404 page triggered by a missing page in /folder/, the browser is trying to download: `/folder/css/style.css` - which obviously isn't there.

*Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an absolute path (start with forward slash from the root of your site) to reference the stylesheets:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" type="text/css" />
```

Or you can use root-relative URLs (start with tilde and forward slash). If the `<link>`-element is in a `<head runat="server">`-element then the root-relative URL will be translated to the right client-side relative path.

```
<head runat="server">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/style.css" type="text/css" />
```

For scripts you have to resolve root-relative URLs yourself. Use the System.Web.UI.Page's ResolveUrl() method:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/scripts/script.js") %>"></script>
```

Or you may just have to set `responseMode` to `redirect` in your configuration.

Comment: Using the absolute paths for all links inside my 404.aspx markup turned out to be a workable solution.  Adding the leading slash to all href= and src= references seemed to work fine for stylesheets, script references, images and hyperlinks.  The markup I got from the designer came with all page-relative URLs.  I'm going to try to ask the designer to use properly qualified URLs in the future, but I probably won't hold my breath!  Thanks @michielvoo!